# Neo4j Cypher performance query optimization

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have the following query:

```
MATCH (dg:DecisionGroup)-[:CONTAINS]->(childD:Decision) 
WHERE dg.id = 1 
MATCH (childD)-[relationshipValueRel4:HAS_VALUE_ON]-(filterCharacteristic4:Characteristic) 
WHERE filterCharacteristic4.id = 4 
WITH relationshipValueRel4, childD, dg 
WHERE  (ANY (id IN [2,3] 
WHERE id IN relationshipValueRel4.optionIds ))  
WITH childD, dg  
OPTIONAL MATCH (childD)-[vg:HAS_VOTE_ON]->(c:Criterion) 
WHERE c.id IN [2, 3] 
WITH childD, dg, vg.avgVotesWeight as weight, vg.totalVotes as totalVotes 
RETURN childD LIMIT 10
```

Profile info of this query:

> Cypher version: CYPHER 3.3, planner: COST, runtime: INTERPRETED. 2773
>   total db hits in **4 ms**

[image]

But when I add one more line to query: `WITH childD , dg , toFloat(sum(weight)) as weight, toInt(sum(totalVotes)) as totalVotes`

and query looks like:

```
MATCH (dg:DecisionGroup)-[:CONTAINS]->(childD:Decision) 
WHERE dg.id = 1 
MATCH (childD)-[relationshipValueRel4:HAS_VALUE_ON]-(filterCharacteristic4:Characteristic) 
WHERE filterCharacteristic4.id = 4 
WITH relationshipValueRel4, childD, dg 
WHERE  (ANY (id IN [2,3] 
WHERE id IN relationshipValueRel4.optionIds ))  
WITH childD, dg  
OPTIONAL MATCH (childD)-[vg:HAS_VOTE_ON]->(c:Criterion) 
WHERE c.id IN [2, 3] 
WITH childD, dg, vg.avgVotesWeight as weight, vg.totalVotes as totalVotes 
WITH childD , dg , toFloat(sum(weight)) as weight, toInt(sum(totalVotes)) as totalVotes  
RETURN childD LIMIT 10
```

The profile info is the following:

> Cypher version: CYPHER 3.3, planner: COST, runtime: INTERPRETED.
>   7818908 total db hits in **6747 ms**

The difference is very huge - **4 ms** vs **6747 ms**

[image]

Why it is working so long with this additional Cypher instruction and how to optimize it ?

Comment: Can you add the PROFILE plan for the other query, and label which is which?

Comment: @InverseFalcon I have the PROFILE plan for the first query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this has to do with the `sum()` operations, they add an EagerAggregation to the plan.

Without the `sum()` operations, you have LIMIT 10. The result can start streaming back to you as soon as the first complete record is obtained, and will stop when you hit the 10th. The planner can be lazy, both in when it can start returning records, and in that it can stop after the 10th record encountered, no need to find all results then get the first slice of 10 afterwards.

However, you can't do that when you have an eager aggregation such as `sum()` (same for `collect()`). Why? Because simply having a single record with childD, dg, and vg isn't enough. Summation depends upon having every single other record obtained with the same childD, dg, and vg variables so weight and total votes can be summed across all those records. And the only way to know that you have all the records you need for the sum to be accurate is to get all results first. And then when the summations are complete, the first 10 records are taken, and the rest cast away.